# What is I/O Area and Memory area in pci driver WEC7

Tags: memory, io, windows-ce, pci, pci-e

I hear the terms I/O area and Memory Area frequently from teammates in my project( PCIe Gigabit ethernet driver development in WEC7) . I have no idea about it . Please knowledge me about it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between I/O and Memory addressing is outlined in [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/490761/clarification-of-the-difference-between-pci-memory-addressing-and-i-o-addressing#490776).

I/O Areas are accessible only through special CPU instructions, whereas Memory Areas can be mapped into the kernel's address space and accessed directly.